# Recorded VBA macro to a general function

Tags: excel, vba

The recorded macro:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
        Range("F9").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("F10").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(DATEDIF(RC[-2],RC[-1],""y"")=0,YEAR(RC[-2]),YEAR(RC[-2])+DATEDIF(RC[-2],RC[-1],""y""))"
        Range("F11").Select
    End Sub
```

And the function is `IF(date.diff(D6;E6;"y")=0;Year(D6);Year(D6)+date.diff(D6;E6;"y"))`

I tried rewriting the code, so that I could use it as a function instead of it being specific on which cells it belonged to. Some of you might be able to help?

Comment: What is the question? First, describe clearly what are trying to do. Then explain what you have done to get there. Then describe the problem. Then ask the question about that problem.

Comment: I made a function using the Excelcode - IF(date.diff(D6;E6;"y")=0;Year(D6);Year(D6)+date.diff(D6;E6;"y")). If its within the same year, it will come out as such. If it's the next year, it will also come out as such. Then I recorded a macro, trying to finde out what was happening, so I could rewrite it in a simpler form than the standard excel format. But now I'm stuck :)

Comment: Clear as mud. You still haven't explained what your end goal is and how you plan to get there.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are trying to do; are you trying to find the number of years between two dates?  Is so you can simply use the built-in `DATEDIFF` function.  If you really want to write a custom function you could do it in a number of ways such as:

```
Function seb(date1 As Date, date2 As Date) As Integer

seb = Year(date1) - Year(date2)

End Function
```

or;

```
Function seb2(date1 As Date, date2 As Date) As Integer

seb = datedif(year2, year1, "y")

End Function
```